# How do I update my Hugo site locally and make sure that the live site (hosted on GitHub pages) reflect the changes?

Tags: github, github-pages, hugo, static-pages

Let me start by saying that I'm very new to this. I have little to no technical background, so this might just be a simple problem, or I did something I shouldn't have done. It's my first time using the command line and dealing with static pages.

I recently deployed my Hugo site to GitHub pages. I only changed the configuration file, and that's it. (I followed [this](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/) and [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-a-personal-website-with-github-pages-and-hugo-6c68592204c7).)

The site is now live at https://USERNAME.github.io/. It's still showing the content of [my chosen theme](https://hugo-whisper.netlify.app/).

A few hours after deploying, I edited some of the local markdown files and pushed the changes. However, the changes aren't reflected on the site.

Now that I realize it, GitHub only displays my site's "public" folder and not all of the files in my local folder.

So, my question is, how can I change and update my site content locally and make sure that the changes are shown on the live site?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: There is a strong possibility your changes went to the incorrect "branch". By default, your branch on GitHub is now `main` while _most_ of the time your GitHub page(s) is built off of `gh-pages`.

Comment: I'm also just learning my way around hugo/github, and I also found the upload process frustrating. Here's some steps I initially missed when learning how to do the process (a) navigate to the public folder (b) if you change a file, you have to add it (ie. `git add about/index.html` (or whatever your modified page is called) and you also have to commit it (c) `git commit -m "update"` and then push it (d) `git push -u origin main`.  There's also a slow propagation time sometimes.